# Is my class a subclass of other generic class?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, subclass

I have an abstract generic class.

```
public abstract class FieldHandlerWithData<DataType extends Parcelable> 
    extends FieldHandler
```

Now I have an object c

```
Class<? extends FieldHandler> c = getHandlerClass(type);
```

and now I want to test if c inherits `FieldHandlerWithData` (directly or indirectly).
**How to determine whether c inherits `FieldHandlerWithData`?**

`c.isAssignableFrom(FieldHandlerWithData.class)` - returns false.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a subclass is an instance of a class at runtime in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410304/check-if-a-subclass-is-an-instance-of-a-class-at-runtime-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the other way around - `FieldHandlerWithData.class.isAssignableFrom(c)`

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this Class object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified Class parameter

So *this* class (the one on which the method is invoked) should be the superclass/superinterface