# Check if a Class Object is subclass of another Class Object in Java

Tags: java, class, reflection

I'm playing around with Java's reflection API and trying to handle some fields. Now I'm stuck with identifying the type of my fields. Strings are easy, just do `myField.getType().equals(String.class)`. The same applies for other non-derived classes. But how do I check derived classes? E.g. `LinkedList` as subclass of `List`. I can't find any `isSubclassOf(...)` or `extends(...)` method. Do I need to walk through all `getSuperClass()` and find my supeclass by my own?

Comment: `LinkedList` isn't a subclass of `List`. It's an *implementation* of `List`.

Comment: *Sub-type* might be a better term

Answer (score 486, accepted):

You want this method:

```
boolean isList = List.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass);
```

where in general, `List` (above) should be replaced with `superclass` and `myClass` should be replaced with `subclass`

From the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)):

> Determines if the class or interface represented by this `Class` object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified `Class` parameter. It returns `true` if so; otherwise it returns `false`. If this `Class` object represents a primitive type, this method returns `true` if the specified `Class` parameter is exactly this `Class` object; otherwise it returns `false`.

**Reference:**

- [**`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class))

---

**Related:**

a) Check if an Object is an instance of a Class or Interface (including subclasses) you know at compile time:

```
boolean isInstance = someObject instanceof SomeTypeOrInterface;
```

Example:

```
assertTrue(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c") instanceof List<?>);
```

b) Check if an Object is an instance of a Class or Interface (including subclasses) you only know at runtime:

```
Class<?> typeOrInterface = // acquire class somehow
boolean isInstance = typeOrInterface.isInstance(someObject);
```

Example:

```
public boolean checkForType(Object candidate, Class<?> type){
    return type.isInstance(candidate);
}
```

Comment: Note the scheme: `SUPERCLASS.isAssignableFrom(SUBCLASS)` This confused me first, altough it is actually obvious considering the naming.

Comment: @TrudleR I agree. Something like `SUPERCLASS.isExtendedBy(SUBCLASS)` would be much easier to understand

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd actually `isExtendedBy` is a bad name as `CLASS.isAssignableFrom(CLASS)` would be true (and therefore `CLASS.isExtendedBy(CLASS)` as well). This would not be what I expected.

Comment: @Qw3ry yes, I'm assuming that's also what the Api authors thought :-)

Answer (score 30):

Another option is instanceof:

```
Object o =...
if (o instanceof Number) {
  double d = ((Number)o).doubleValue(); //this cast is safe
}
```

Comment: Good call (+1). And then there is also the combination of the two mechanisms: `Class.isInstance(object)` http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: This would imply, that you instanciate that `Field`. But I just want to "look" at my class and its fields, don't want to "try them out".

Comment: I see this method much cleaner and clearer than the "isAssignableFrom" way, in the case you need to check the inheritance tree of an object.

Comment: Keep in mind that `instanceof` also works for parent (in this case `Number`) itself not only childrens

Answer (score 10):

*instanceof* works on instances, i.e. on Objects. Sometimes you want to work directly with classes. In this case you can use the *asSubClass* method of the Class class.
Some examples:

1)

```
    Class o=Object.class;
    Class c=Class.forName("javax.swing.JFrame").asSubclass(o);
```

this will go through smoothly because JFrame is subclass of Object. c will contain a Class object representing the JFrame class.

2)

```
    Class o=JButton.class;
    Class c=Class.forName("javax.swing.JFrame").asSubclass(o);
```

this will launch a **java.lang.ClassCastException** because JFrame is NOT subclass of JButton. c will not be initialized.

3)

```
    Class o=Serializable.class;
    Class c=Class.forName("javax.swing.JFrame").asSubclass(o);
```

this will go through smoothly because JFrame implements the java.io.Serializable interface. c will contain a Class object representing the JFrame class.

Of course the needed imports have to be included.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me:

```
protected boolean isTypeOf(String myClass, Class<?> superClass) {
    boolean isSubclassOf = false;
    try {
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(myClass);
        if (!clazz.equals(superClass)) {
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
            isSubclassOf = isTypeOf(clazz.getName(), superClass);
        } else {
            isSubclassOf = true;
        }

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        /* Ignore */
    }
    return isSubclassOf;
}
```

Comment: Works nice, but you might have to add a null check after clazz = clazz.getSuperclass() in case you hit java.lang.Object who does not have a super class.

Answer (score 4):

A recursive method to check if a `Class<?>` is a sub class of another `Class<?>`...

Improved version of [@To Kra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599213/to-kra)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615662/4298200):

```
protected boolean isSubclassOf(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> superClass) {
    if (superClass.equals(Object.class)) {
        // Every class is an Object.
        return true;
    }
    if (clazz.equals(superClass)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        // every class is Object, but superClass is below Object
        if (clazz.equals(Object.class)) {
            // we've reached the top of the hierarchy, but superClass couldn't be found.
            return false;
        }
        // try the next level up the hierarchy.
        return isSubclassOf(clazz, superClass);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an improved version of @schuttek's answer. It is improved because it correctly return false for primitives (e.g. isSubclassOf(int.class, Object.class) => false) and also correctly handles interfaces (e.g. isSubclassOf(HashMap.class, Map.class) => true).

```
static public boolean isSubclassOf(final Class<?> clazz, final Class<?> possibleSuperClass)
{
    if (clazz == null || possibleSuperClass == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (clazz.equals(possibleSuperClass))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        final boolean isSubclass = isSubclassOf(clazz.getSuperclass(), possibleSuperClass);

        if (!isSubclass && clazz.getInterfaces() != null)
        {
            for (final Class<?> inter : clazz.getInterfaces())
            {
                if (isSubclassOf(inter, possibleSuperClass))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return isSubclass;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

//Inheritance

```
    class A {
      int i = 10;
      public String getVal() {
        return "I'm 'A'";
      }
    }

    class B extends A {
      int j = 20;
      public String getVal() {
        return "I'm 'B'";
      }
    }

    class C extends B {
        int k = 30;
        public String getVal() {
          return "I'm 'C'";
        }
    }
```

//Methods

```
    public static boolean isInheritedClass(Object parent, Object child) {
      if (parent == null || child == null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return isInheritedClass(parent.getClass(), child.getClass());
      }
    }

    public static boolean isInheritedClass(Class<?> parent, Class<?> child) {
      if (parent == null || child == null) {
        return false;
      } else {
        if (parent.isAssignableFrom(child)) {
          // is child or same class
          return parent.isAssignableFrom(child.getSuperclass());
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

// Test the code

```
    System.out.println("isInheritedClass(new A(), new B()):" + isInheritedClass(new A(), new B()));
    System.out.println("isInheritedClass(new A(), new C()):" + isInheritedClass(new A(), new C()));
    System.out.println("isInheritedClass(new A(), new A()):" + isInheritedClass(new A(), new A()));
    System.out.println("isInheritedClass(new B(), new A()):" + isInheritedClass(new B(), new A()));


    System.out.println("isInheritedClass(A.class, B.class):" + isInheritedClass(A.class, B.class));
    System.out.println("isInheritedClass(A.class, C.class):" + isInheritedClass(A.class, C.class));
    System.out.println("isInheritedClass(A.class, A.class):" + isInheritedClass(A.class, A.class));
    System.out.println("isInheritedClass(B.class, A.class):" + isInheritedClass(B.class, A.class));
```

//Result

```
    isInheritedClass(new A(), new B()):true
    isInheritedClass(new A(), new C()):true
    isInheritedClass(new A(), new A()):false
    isInheritedClass(new B(), new A()):false
    isInheritedClass(A.class, B.class):true
    isInheritedClass(A.class, C.class):true
    isInheritedClass(A.class, A.class):false
    isInheritedClass(B.class, A.class):false
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@To-kra's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1599213/to-kra) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31615662/8734046). If someone doesn't like recurrence:

```
    public static boolean isSubClassOf(Class<?> clazz, Class<?> superClass) {
        if(Object.class.equals(superClass)) {
            return true;
        }

        for(; !Object.class.equals(clazz); clazz = clazz.getSuperclass()) {
            if(clazz.getSuperclass().equals(superClass)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

NOTE: no null checking for clarity.