# Can a class have a "IS A Relationship" with itself?

Tags: java, scjp

```
class A
{
}
class B extend A
{
    int i;
    int j;
}
```

Can a class have an **IS-A Relationship** with itself?
In this question, **B is an A**, right?
But can class `B` have an **IS-A** relationship with class `B`?

Comment: Are you asking if, for example, a dog **is a** dog?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584541/check-if-a-class-is-subclass-of-another-class-in-java

Comment: Yes same question is asked in my ocjp exam..

Comment: Are you sure that's what it asks? _is a relationship_ isn't a technical term.  I would think OCJP deals with technical Java Language concepts.

Comment: Is a tautology true? This question doesn't lead anywhere. There is no truth left to be discovered. I think you may have misunderstood what they were asking. A question that would take you somewhere is: A extends B, B is a A, Can it be possible that A is a B?

Comment: It's *like* asking yourself if you are yourself.

Comment: it depends on what the meaning of *is* is.

Answer (score 1):

It's an identity (and tautology) - an object of type `B` will always be able to describe itself as an object of type `B`.

The further extensions of the is-a relationship pertain to hierarchies of inheritance; that is to say, since `B extends A`, `B` **is-an** `A`.  This allows you to write the following expression:

```
A anA = new B();
```

But `B` is a `B` too.  It hasn't lost that part of its identity because it now inherits from another class.

Comment: In a nutshell:  *every* class has an "is-a" relationship with itself.