# Check if object is cast to its dynamic type in Java

Tags: java, casting

I would like to know if there is a way to check if an reference has been cast to the exact Type of its object. For example...

```
String s = new String("test");
checkCast(s); //Returns true, since s has a dynamic and static type of String.
Object o = (Object) s;
checkCast(o); //Returns false, since the dynamic and static type of o are not equal.
```

Some background about the actual problem...

I have a hierarchy of classes A, B, and C like below:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
```

And then I have a `LinkedList<A>` of A objects. This list may contain any of the above classes. I then have a method like so...

```
<T extends A> T getFirstObjInList(){
   //Iterate over the list and return the first object that is of type T...
}
```

**I need to know how to check if an object from my list is of the Generic Type passed into the method.** I can't use instanceof because erasure etc. and I'd really prefer to not change the method's heading, i.e., adding any parameters or anything like that.

What I first tried doing is casting each object in the list to T in a for loop, and if a ClassCastException is thrown, continue iterating, but that obviously didn't work with the hierarchy I have, so now I'm looking for a way to check if an object has been casted to its dynamic type. **If the object in the list is of the type specified, then when casted, its static type won't change,** so if i can compare the two types, I can figure out if the object is an instance of the generic type given.

Note: `list.getFirst() instanceof T` doesn't compile due to type erasure.

Comment: This question smells like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels This was more for curiosity, but I'll add in the problem I'm having anyways...

Comment: I think what you're looking for is similar to the approaches discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584541/check-if-a-class-is-subclass-of-another-class-in-java

Comment: @KevinHooke I did see that page, but I couldn't find a way to get a class object from the generic type. If I could get the class of `T`, I think  `isInstance()` would work nicely, though.

Comment: I was going to suggest instanceof, but you say that's out due to erasure... Have you actually tested that? In any case, to expand on what @HovercraftFullOfEels said, if you are checking the class and then performing different behaviour for different classes, you should probably use polymorphism to achieve the same result in a cleaner way.

Comment: Your approach, even if you could get it to work looks to be quite brittle and thus easy to break. If simple polymorphism as suggested by @Maybe_Factor isn't enough, then you should look into a higher degree of indirection such as can be obtained by using design patterns. A Visitor Pattern might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor In reply to the instanceof solution, yes. I did try it at first, but the program won't compile; Java doesn't allow instanceof to be used with generic types. :( But anyways, can you explain what you meant by polymorphism as a solution?

Comment: @YorickIsTheBest can you update your question with an example of what won't compile and maybe we can help with the specific issue you're seeing? Also, it might make sense to describe what it is that you're trying to do (why do you need to determine the exact type?) because there might be a better/easier approach you could use instead?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I do have a solution to this, which is to add an actual `Class<?>` parameter and then check if classes are equal, however, I originally wanted to know if there was a way to solve the same problem without one. Anyways, I looked up the Visitor Pattern, but I don't see how it would help. I couldn't implement it though, because I don't want any of my classes to depend on another class (like the visitor class); I don't know how many will be made or who will make them and I wouldn't want to edit the visitor class anytime one was made.

Comment: I fear that you're worried about the wrong problems as it's usually much better to use interfaces and proper design patterns than to depend on kludges.

Comment: @KevinHooke I added the compilation issue and the first bold text is what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I get what you mean, but an interface wouldn't really help with this, and it isn't really a design related problem. The method I gave was a static method in one of my classes. This class has a list of `GameObjects` and a method that takes in an `GameObject`. This method searches the list to find the closest `GameObject` of the sub-type specified to the `GameObject` passed as a parameter. More `GameObjects` will be added in the future and maybe some mods to the game will add their own (where they wouldn't be able to edit my classes, but they'd be able to extend them.)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So I wanted to have one method which could take in a Generic Type and an object, so when people add their own classes to my game, the method will still be compatible. (The new Classes could just be passed in the generic type.) Anyways, that's a brief overview of the design at the moment.

Comment: @YorickIsTheBest I'm not sure polymorphism is appropriate in this situation, but sometimes we see people using the type of an object to decide what to do, resulting in a bit if statement with a bunch of instanceofs in the conditions. I'm curious if you could modify shmosel's answer to use T.getClass() rather than have to pass in a type parameter?

Comment: @Maybe_Factor Do you mean to remove `type` as a parameter and try to compare using `a.getClass()==T.getClass()`?

Comment: @Maybe_Factor You probably mean `T.class`, which isn't valid in Java, because of type erasure.

Comment: @Maybe_Factor If so, the I'm disappointed to tell you that that wouldn't work. :( Java won't let me call anything off of `T` since Type Parameters aren't really objects. I had tried to get an uninitialized reference of Type `T` and do something with that (like so: `T object;`) but I couldn't call anything off of it, since it wasn't initialized, and setting it to null didn't work either. I suppose that this might just be a limit to Java and I'll use the Class<?> solution for now, but if I find something else, I'll post it here. I did hear someone mention TypeTokens, but don't know what they do.

Comment: @YorickIsTheBest Yeah, that's what I meant, but I don't think it would work now that I'm looking at it.

Comment: TypeTokens are for when you need a type with a generic parameter, like `Class<List<Foo>>`. Not related to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may have concluded by now, your method signature isn't viable because of type erasure. I would recommend passing an explicit type:

```
<T extends A> T getFirstObjInList(Class<T> type) {
    for (A a : list) {
        if (a.getClass() == type) {
            return type.cast(a);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```