# how to check if an instance of an abstract object belongs to a particular subclass

Tags: java, object, inheritance, instance, abstract-class

I am referencing this duplicate question here:
[Check if a Class Object is subclass of another Class Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584541/check-if-a-class-object-is-subclass-of-another-class-object-in-java)

I have an abstract parent class named 'Figure' of which I have two subclasses, 'Circle' and 'Rectangle' both of which extend this abstract parent.  I am trying to determine if a Figure object is of type Circle or type Rectangle.

My original code was:

```
 public boolean isInstanceOfRectangle(Figure figure)
 {
     boolean isInstance = figure instanceof Rectangle;
     System.out.println("instance of rectangle!");

     return isInstance;
  }
```

After studying the linked question above, I have rewritten my code as follows:

```
public boolean isRectangle()
{
    boolean isInstance = Figure.class.isAssignableFrom(Rectangle); 
    System.out.println("instance of rectangle!");
    return isInstance;  
 }
```

For some reason this does not work unless I include the following in my main class:

```
public Class<?> Rectangle;
public Class<?> Circle1;
```

I'm not sure the significance of including this in my class, if I do not, it seems to require that I include it as a parameter in my method.  I am unable to correctly invoke and test this method because I am unsure what parameter to pass into the method when invoked.  I'd like to write something like:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    if ((isRectangle(shape1)))
    addRectangle((Rectangle)shape1, e.getComponent().getForeground());

    else if ((isCircle(shape1)))
    addCircle((Circle) shape1, e.getComponent().getForeground());   
 }
```

where 'shape1' is a Figure object that was instantiated as either a circle or a rectangle.  Because the parameter is of type Figure, I am unsure how to define the 'isRectangle' method to take a Figure object (the abstract parent) and determine specifically which subclass it is an instance of.  Or preferrably to take no parameter and just do the work by using the Figure object to invoke the method.  I am a bit confused how to proceed.

*Edit: upon user suggestions, I have rewritten the following <strike>which does NOT appear to work because in both cases the output is FALSE.</strike>

```
Figure circleObj = new Circle(Color.BLUE);

System.out.println(isInstanceOfRectangle(circleObj));
System.out.println(isInstanceOfCircle(circleObj));

public static boolean isInstanceOfRectangle(Figure figure)
{
    boolean isInstance = figure instanceof Rectangle;
    if (isInstance == true)
        System.out.println("instance of rectangle!");
    else
        System.out.println("is NOT a rectangle");
    return isInstance;
}


public static boolean isInstanceOfCircle(Figure figure)
{
    boolean isInstance = figure instanceof Circle;
    if (isInstance == true)
        System.out.println("instance of circle!");
    else
        System.out.println("is NOT a circle");
    return isInstance;
}
```

Comment: You should almost always restructure your code to avoid needing to do that.

Comment: Both cases is false because you are checking for `figure instanceof Rectangle` in both methods. You should be checking for `figure instanceof Circle` in the second one.

Comment: as @chrylis mentioned, you should be restructuring the code in such a way so that you can avoid such checks. One option is to make a abstract method in Figure and override it in your Circle/Rectangle classes to do the behaviour you want.

Answer (score 4):

That will always return `false` since the `Figure` `Class` instance is not a subclass of the `Rectangle` `Class` instance :

```
boolean isInstance = Figure.class.isAssignableFrom(Rectangle.class);
```

You want to generally invoke `isAssignableFrom()` on the class of a variable which you don't know the runtime type.
It would make more sense :

```
Figure figure = ...;
boolean isInstance = Rectangle.class.isAssignableFrom(figure.getClass());
```

That allows to know whether the instance of the class of the `figure` variable *IS* a `Rectangle`.

Introducing a method to handle the requirement would make still more sense as it is dynamic and it also allows to handle different class compatibility checks :

```
  public static boolean isInstanceOf(Figure figure, Class<?> clazz){
    boolean isInstance = clazz.isAssignableFrom(figure.getClass());
    return isInstance;
  }
```

And you could so use it such as :

```
System.out.println(isInstanceOf(new Rectangle(), Rectangle.class));    
System.out.println(isInstanceOf(new Circle(), Rectangle.class));    
System.out.println(isInstanceOf(new Figure(), Rectangle.class));
```

That prints :

> true
>
> false
>
> false

And of course all of these will output`true` as a `Figure`, a `Circle` and a `Rectangle` are `Figure`s :

```
System.out.println(isInstanceOf(new Rectangle(), Figure.class));    
System.out.println(isInstanceOf(new Circle(), Figure.class));    
System.out.println(isInstanceOf(new Figure(), Figure.class));
```

Comment: Additionally, if you know the class you're checking `isAssignableFrom`, it might be easier to write `figure instanceof Rectangle`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the .getClas() method to find the subclass

```
    Rectangle aRectangle = new Rectangle();
    if (aRectangle.getClass == Rectangle.class){
        // Do what you would do if it was a rectangle
        System.out.println("you have a rectangle");
    }   
    else{
        // The figure is not a rectangle 
        System.out.println("the figure is not a rectangle");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don’t see much reason to complicate your code with assignable. Your original code works. More than that, checking variable’s class is not a good practice, try to restructure your code. (Check polymorphism, Barbara Liskov principle and Interface segregation principle)
And for clarifying things: Figure is not an object since it’s abstract, it’s type. The type is what stands on the left side of variable declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Your original implementation is correct and the simplest one until we get pattern matching in Java.

More detailed explaination:

`instanceof` operator can be used to check if an object is an instance of a particular class. This matches your intent.

You can achieve similar functionality with `ClassA.isAssignableFrom(ClassB)`. Here, ClassA is superclass and ClassB is a subclass. Note that this function compares two classes (instances of `Class<?>`), not an instance against a class.

You can get the class from an instance using `getClass` method, and thus, the resulting code will look like:

```
Rectange.class.isAssignableFrom(figure.getClass())
```

Your proposed check

```
Figure.class.isAssignableFrom(Rectangle);
```

has multiple problems:

- syntax error: you need a `Class<?>` instance on the right side, you could use class literal `Rectangle.class`, but this checks a trivial fact and is always true.
- to fix this error, you defined a variable `Class<?> Rectangle`, but this variable does not have any relation with `Rectangle` class, unless explicitely initialized with class literal `Rectangle.class`
- you dont use figure instance anywhere

Comment: I have heard that the original implementation works but when I attempt to instantiate a circle object I get false for both circle and rectangle types

Comment: You test agains Rectangle in your isInstanceOfCircle method

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to chime in here and point out a bug in these methods:

```
public static boolean isInstanceOfRectangle(Figure figure)
{
    //boolean isInstance = figure instanceof Rectangle;
    boolean isInstance = figure instanceof Rectangle;
    if (isInstance == true)
        System.out.println("instance of rectangle!");
    else
        System.out.println("is NOT a rectangle");
    return isInstance;
}


public static boolean isInstanceOfCircle(Figure figure)
{
    //boolean isInstance = figure instanceof Rectangle;
    boolean isInstance = figure instanceof Rectangle;
    if (isInstance == true)
        System.out.println("instance of circle!");
    else
        System.out.println("is NOT a circle");
    return isInstance;
}
```

In the second method, the behaviour you want is for it to check whether or not it is a circle. But instead, you check if it is a rectangle.

Instead of `figure instanceof Rectangle` you should be checking `figure instanceof Circle`

PS. it is acceptable to use `instanceof`. Anything else is overkill.