# Java reflection - identify method return type

Tags: java, reflection

I am having a use case to identify the return type of a method is of `List` type or not. To check the return type, I am using `Class#isAssignable` method and came across this behavior.

```
public class ObjectReturnType {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method1 = ObjectReturnType.class.getDeclaredMethod("objectReturnType");
        Class<? extends Object> returnType1 = method1.getReturnType();
        if (returnType1.isAssignableFrom(List.class)) {
            System.out.println("Yes it is.");
        }

        Method declaredMethod2 = ObjectReturnType.class.getDeclaredMethod("listReturnType");
        Class<? extends Object> returnType2 = declaredMethod2.getReturnType();
        if (returnType2.isAssignableFrom(List.class)) {
            System.out.println("Yes it is.");
        }

    }

    public Object objectReturnType() {
        return null;
    }

    public List<String> listReturnType() {
        return List.of("");
    }
}
```

Both methods are going through the `if` condition, I was expecting only the `listReturnType` method to go through the `if` condition, not sure why the `objectReturnType` method is going the `if` condition. Can someone help me to understand this behavior?

Comment: `List` is assignable _to_ `Object`, so `Object` is assignable _from_ `List`. Nothing is wrong here. Did you mean to reverse the two types? `if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType1))`

Comment: Possibly related: [Check if a Class Object is subclass of another Class Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4584541)

Comment: Just try `Class<?> object = Object.class, list = List.class; System.out.println(object.isAssignableFrom(list)); System.out.println(list.isAssignableFrom(object));`

Answer (score 0):

You can check using a class name like this

```java
public class ObjectReturnType {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method1 = ObjectReturnType.class.getDeclaredMethod("objectReturnType");
        Class<?> returnType1 = method1.getReturnType();
        if (List.class.getName().equals(returnType1.getName())) {
            System.out.println("Yes it is.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Yes it not List.");
        }

        Method declaredMethod2 = ObjectReturnType.class.getDeclaredMethod("listReturnType");
        Class<?> returnType2 = declaredMethod2.getReturnType();
        if (List.class.getName().equals(returnType2.getName())) {
            System.out.println("Yes it is.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Yes it not List.");
        }
    }

    public Object objectReturnType() {
        return null;
    }

    public List<String> listReturnType() {
        return List.of("");
    }

}
```

Output will be

```
No it not List.
Yes it is.
```