# Calling an abstract method from a group of abstract subclasses

Tags: java, abstract-class, subclassing, abstract-methods

I am creating an abstract `GUIClickableObject` class extending a `GUIObject` class with an abstract method `public void onClick()`. When I create a new subclass extending the `GUIClickableObject`, I instantiate the abstract `onClick()` method depending on the Clickable object's action.

I have my mouse's position and the object's position, so I can easily locate it, but I need to create a search function that searches through my GUIClickable objects and then calls their `onClick()` method if the mouse clicks and releases on the object.

- a) create an ArrayList/Array/Group that contains the different subclasses of the GUIClickable object,
- b) iterate through them, and c) then call the abstract 'onClick()' method?

Apparently I can't just create an ArrayList of GUIClickableObjects and insert my subclasses into it, right?

Comment: Post the relevant part(s) of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a generified list

```
List<? extends GUIClickableObjects> gcos = new ArrayList<? extends GUIClickableObject>();
```

Now you can add any subclass of `GUIClickableObject`.

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently I can't just create an ArrayList of GUIClickableObjects and insert my subclasses into it, right?

why is that so. you should be able to create an arraylist which will accept objects of subclass to GUIClickableObjects. In case you want to specifically check object belong to which sub class you can simply do "instance of" check

[How to check if a subclass is an instance of a class at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410304/check-if-a-subclass-is-an-instance-of-a-class-at-runtime-in-java)

More over please elaborate on what you are thinking or facing.