# know type of inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

If I have a inheritance class like

```
class Animals{}
class Dog extends Animals{}
class Cat extends Animals{}
```

How I can know which type of class are? (I mean, if a want know if one object below to dog or cat)

I have an `ArrayList` of `Animals` who contain `Cat`s and `Dog`s. I save this information in a file, for later load the information. But the problem is when I want load the information I need to know which type of class is, for call the dog or cat constructor (cat and dogs have different constructor parameters).

So one of my solutions is store the type of object for when I load the information call the correct constructor. Is any better solution for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if a subclass is an instance of a class at runtime in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2410304/check-if-a-subclass-is-an-instance-of-a-class-at-runtime-in-java)

Comment: @Beko: the `instanceof` operator is considered to be bad OO-design, because it is not scalable.

Comment: `instanceof` just won't work here. He's trying to find the instance of data stored in a file...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are saving the information, you can also print out the type.

For example, you can use something like:

```
for (final Animals animal : myAnimalList){
    output.print(animal.getClass().getSimpleName());
    output.println(animal.getData());
}
```

For instances of `Dog`, this will print out `"Dog"` and for instances of `Cat`, it will print out `"Cat"`. Followed by the `getData()` information. This is assuming that `getData()` would contain the appropriate data for printing out the information.

Then you can achieve something like:

```
Dog[name=Ruff, age=17, favoriteToy=Ball]
Cat[name=Tom, age=102, hates=Everyone]
```

Then, you can easily fill in the information required to reconstruct dogs and cats, based off of the required fields.

That being said, you can then write this out to the file. This is, as suggested in your question, similar to the way you are already doing this.

**This has already been done before, so creating your own methods and all that is not recommended.**

---

The alternative is to have a unique identifier for each class (think `serialVersionUID`).

This is just a form of [Serialization](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_serialization.htm). Having basic `read` and `write` methods can then handle parsing the correct data on a class-to-class basis.

It would be far better to implement `Serializable` for the `Animals` class, then sent fields you don't want to be written and read to `transient`.

Then, you can just fill all the appropriate methods with these signatures:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException;
```

Comment: What's wrong with *Java's default serializer*? No identifiers you have to care for, it handles the entire process all by itself.

Comment: @CommuSoft nothing, that is why I said creating your own is a bad idea and that you should use the serializer....

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to reimplement the serialization of java.
Instead of that

1. you should make the class Animals to implement the Serializable marker interface
2. simple write to and then read from the file your array [like described here](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-serialize-arraylist-in-java/)

Answer (score -1):

use `getClass()` for example:

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
if (dog.getClass().equals(Dog.class)) {
    System.out.printf("Its dog!");
}
```

Or as Beko pointed out

```
Animal dog = new Dog();
if (dog instanceof Dog) {
    System.out.printf("Its dog!");
}
```

Comment: First of all, `.getClass()` and `instanceof` behave differently, a class `BlackDog extends Dog` would fail the first `if` and succeed the second, and furthermore using such tests is in general bad design.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils: well the question is vague on that part. It is not entirely clear if the OP has written some kind of parser him/herself that parses the file into an `ArrayList`, if one however wishes to perform different operations for `Cat`s and `Dog`s one should use a virtual method. In case one wishes to store/load to/from files, the *Java Serializer* is the best option.